# A program that counts unique elements in an un-ordered array

Tags: c, arrays, unique, counter, element

```
int num_distinct(int a[], int n)
{
  int i, k, j, count=0;
  int max = a[0];

  for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
    if (max < a[i]) {
      max = a[i];
    }
  }
  for (k = 0; k < n; ++k) {
    for (j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
      if (a[j] == max) {
        ++count;
        --max;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return (count);
}
```

What i tried to do is find the max in the array and compare that to the rest of the elements in the array. It works, but when the array skips a number i.e. (1,2,2,5,6,7,8) <-- it skipped 3 and 4. My code will only count 8,7,6,5 which returns 4 unique numbers.

Comment: Well I am trying to create a function in which it counts all the unique elements in the array. for example a[1,4,2,6,6,7,8,5,5,4], this a aray would have 7 unique elements. My program goes and finds the max of the array and then does comparisons to count the unique elements... However its buggy, when you enter and array but skip a number (for example 1,2,4,5 , it will not count all unique numbers... I don't know what's wrong with it.

Comment: You only decrement `max` upon finding a match, which you will not do when you have a hole in your sequence. Ex: your test vector will find 8, 7, 6, and 5, but as there is no 4 `max` is never adjusted to look for `3`, `2`, or `1`, and the double-loop eventually terminates with a sum count of the four items you found.

Answer (score 3):

just to let you know, @kcDod's algorithm is flawed. It won't count elements like this: 1, 2, 3, 4, 9000, 4, 2
try and you will see:

the below code will count regardless of the elements and requires much less power, you don't count unique elements by incrementing or decrementing the maximum in an array, I don't know where you got that idea.

```
int unique_elements(int arr[], int len) {

    int counted[len], j, n, count, flag;

    counted[0] = arr[0]; 

    count = 1;/*one element is counted*/

        for(j=0; j <= len-1; ++j) {
        flag = 1;;
        /*the counted array will always have 'count' elements*/
        for(n=0; n < count; ++n) {
            if(arr[j] == counted[n]) {
                flag = 0;
            }
        }
        if(flag == 1) {
            ++count;
            counted[count-1] = arr[j];
        }
    }
    return count;
}


int main(void) {
    int arr[13] = {1, 2, 2, 123121, 123121, 3, 5, 6 , 7, 7, 14, 2, 16};
    printf("%d", unique_elements(arr, 13));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes simplicity rules.

```
int unique_elements(int arr, int len)
{
     if (len <= 0) return 0;
     int unique = 1;

     for (int outer = 1; outer < len; ++outer)
     {
        int is_unique = 1;
        for (int inner = 0; is_unique && inner < outer; ++inner)
        {  
             if (arr[inner] == arr[outer]) is_unique = 0;
        }
        if (is_unique) ++unique;
     }
     return unique;
}
```

The logic is that the outer loop picks the value to be tested, and the inner loop checks it against all preceding values.   If the value is found, it is not unique, so the count is incremented.

The advantage of this is no usage of temporary storage (whether a VLA, or use of malloc()).   It also does not try to work out the max, or count number of repetitions, or anything like that.

The worst case execution time is if all values are unique (i.e. no repeated values in the array).

Comment: `int arr` makes more sense as `int *arr` or even better `const int *arr`.

Answer (score 2):

This shall work .. Replace second for loop set with this.

```
int flag = 0; // We need to flag that we found a max in the iteration. So don't count again

for (k = 0; k < n;){
     for (j = 0; j < n; ++j) {         
          if (a[j] == max){
             if (flag==0){
                 ++count; // We count an occurrence only once 
                 flag = 1;
              }
             k++; // We should decrease the search when we found an element from original array
          }
      }
    // Reset parameters
    --max;
    flag = 0;
}
```

A working example :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a[7] = { 7,2,2,4,5,6,7};
    int n = 7; // Number of elements in the array 

    int max=0;
    int i, k, j=0;

    for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (max < a[i])
         {
            max = a[i];
        }
    }

    int count=0;
    int flag = 0;

    for (k = 0; k < n;)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n; ++j)
        {
            if (a[j] == max)
            {
                if (flag==0)
                {
                    ++count;
                    flag = 1;
                }
             k++;
         }
        }
        --max;
         flag = 0;
    }

    printf("Unique elements : %d\n",count);
}
```

Output :

```
Unique elements : 5
```

Comment: Thanks, but this just counts all elements not unique elements.

Comment: int arr[] = {1,2,2,5,6,7,8,3,9,1};
  int dis_num = num_distinct(arr,10); the output is 8 instead of 7 ..

Comment: shouldn't it be 6 ?? because 2 and 1 are not unique

Comment: occurences of 2 and 1 are more then 1 times

Comment: @headnangondal - from OP owners comment "for example a[1,4,2,6,6,7,8,5,5,4], this a aray would have 7 unique elements".

Comment: It worked perfectly thank you so much^.^ I can't believe I missed that I have been coding all day, must of gotten tunnel vision.. Thanks again!!!!

Comment: @user3539833 Problem was with your algorithm. next time before you code write down it on a paper and check.. Mark answer as 'correct' if you accept it..

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm might take much longer time when the max value in the array is very big. Memorising which element was counted already seems to be better in order to reduce computational complexity.

My code below memorises which element was counted and skips counting an element if it was counted already. I use a flag array to memorise counted element.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int num_distinct(int a[], int n) {
    int* flag;
    int all_counted = 0;
    int i, cur, count = 0;
    int cur_flag;

    flag = (int*)malloc(n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) flag[i] = 0;

    while (all_counted == 0) {
        cur_flag = 0;
        for (i = count; i < n; i++) {
            if (cur_flag == 0 && flag[i] == 0) {
                flag[i] = 1;
                cur_flag = 1;
                cur = a[i];
                count++;
            } else if (cur_flag == 1 && cur == a[i]) {
                flag[i] = 1;
            }
        }
        if (cur_flag == 0) all_counted = 1;
    }
    free(flag);
    return count;
}
```

Comment: `flag = (int*)malloc(n);` too small an allocation.  Use `flag = malloc(sizeof *flag * n);`.